# How do I define an IF statement for a cell contains a specific value in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that adds a timestamp to a cell when another cell in the row is initially filled in. What I would like to do is only timestamp when a cell contains the word "Completed". It doesn't seem to be working though.

```
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet 1';
var DATETIME_HEADER = 'datetime';

function getDatetimeCol(){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(DATETIME_HEADER);
  return colindex+1;
}

function onEdit(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var datecell = ss.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), getDatetimeCol());

  //Here's the line where I added an "if the active cell is labelled completed then add a timestamp to the datetime column"
  if (ss.getName() == SHEET_NAME && cell.getColumn() == 8 && !cell.isBlank() && datecell.isBlank() && cell.getValues == "Completed") {      
    datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
  }
}
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const col = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().reduce((a,h,i)=> (a[h]=i+1,a),{});
  const dateCell = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,col['datetime']);
  if (sh.getName() == "SHEET_NAME" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && datecell.isBlank() && e.value == "Completed") {      
    datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work but switching the cell.getValues == "Completed" with e.value == "Completed" was exactly what I needed. Thanks!